# Keycloak logout all user session

Tags: node.js, session, keycloak, openid-connect, logout

I use Keycloak for authentication in my frontend and my backend.

In the frontend I use the [keycloak-js](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak) library and in the backend I use [keycloak-connect](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect) as an express middleware. In the backend I also use a session store as described in the [NodeJS documentation for Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_nodejs_adapter).

When I call the logout endpoint in the frontend/keycloak-js I am correctly logged out and in the Keycloak admin interface I see no more active sessions.
However, I still get authenticated when making backend requests. Only after I clear the session storage or call the `/logout` endpoint on the backend I am finally not authenticated on the backend anymore.

After searching for a solution to this I am not very clear on what the approach should be.

At the moment I see the following option:

1. Remove the relevant entry from the session storage. I don't know how to do this though as the entries have a different format than the `session_state` so I don't know which one to delete.
2. Call the `/logout` endpoint of the backend that is automatically created by the `keycloak-connect` middleware. The problem there is that I don't get redirected back to the frontend application afterwards and it also means an additional manual step to log out.
3. Somehow use the back-channel functionality. I just come across this keyword and the `Backchannel logout URL` setting for clients. However, I did not really understand how this works and putting my `<BACKEND>/logout` url there doesn't work.

Does anyone have experience or an idea how I can remove this session from the backend session storage on logout in the frontend?

Many thanks in advance!